# stdcall calling convention and using pinvoke in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, calling-convention, stdcall

I created a DLL file which includes two empty functions below.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall myFunc1() {
    // just empty function
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl myFunc2() {
    // just empty function
}
```

In C#, I could call the functions using `DLLImport` attribute like below.

```
[DllImport("myDLL", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private extern static void myFunc1();

[DllImport("myDLL", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private extern static void myFunc2();
```

So I tried again directly with `LoadLibrary()` of kernel32.dll instead of `DllImport` attribute.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private delegate void MyFunc1();

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void MyFunc2();
```

However a runtime error occurs when I call MyFunc1() **where MyFunc2() works**.

So I replaced `__stdcall` with `__cdecl` in C++, recompiled the DLL and then called MyFunc1() again in C#.

And.. It worked.

**Why on earth doesn't __stdcall calling convention work with pinvoke in C#?**

Comment: `DllImport` *is* P/Invoke. What on Earth are you trying to do? :D `UnmanagedFunctionPointer` handles marshalling a managed delegate as an unmanaged function pointer (as the name suggests) - it has nothing to do with calling an unmanaged function in a DLL. Okay, not "nothing" - obviously, you have a delegate you can pass or receive from the unmanaged side, but that's not what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Also, as per documentation for `UnmanagedFunctionPointer`, `if you do not specify a field name, UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute is ignored.` - I don't see you specifying any name.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm using LoadLibrary(), FreeLibrary() and GetProcAddress() of "kernel32.dll" this time. I didn't post the rest of the code because I thought it was just a basic thing to expert guys here.

Comment: Sorry to ask such a basic question, but how do I specify the name of the function in UnmanagedFunctionPointer??
I'm just getting the pointer using Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer, and I specified the name there.

Comment: `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` expects a type for the second parameter. Pass it `typeof(MyFunc1)` ;-)

Comment: Thanks but I said I'm doing it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's happening here is that when you switch from `__cdecl` to `__stdcall` in the C++ code, the compiler decorates the name by which the function is exported. Instead of `myFunc1` it is exported as `myFunc1@0` or perhaps `_myFunc1@0`. All the same, the name is decorated. You can check that this is so with `dumpbin` or Dependency Viewer.

When you call `GetProcAddress`, it cannot find a function named `myFunc1` and so returns `NULL`. You don't check for return values, and so carry on regardless. When you try to call the function, a run time error is thrown.

I've had to guess most of this because you did not show complete code. The other big lesson is to check for errors when calling Win32 functions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it as you said. If the reason is the name decoration, what can I do? I thought the keyword extern "C" would prevent problems related to naming.

Comment: Need to use a def file to export

Comment: Checked with dumpbin and it was exactly as you said. I thought I was checking null but there was a stupid mistake as well. "if ((dgMyFunc1 = (MyFunc)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(GetProcAddress(myDLL, "myFunc1"), typeof(MyFunc))) == null)"..

Comment: Thanks again, btw Dependency Viewer is better than dumpbin?

Comment: `IntPtr fnptr = GetProcAddress(myDLL, "myFunc1"); if (fnptr == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();`

Comment: Dependency Viewer is different. It can do more. It's visual. dumpbin lists exports perfectly well though.

Comment: Just curious but how can I get a function pointer with ordinal number in C# using GetProcAddress? Like "GetProcAddress(myDLL, (LPCSTR)5);" in C++. I know [DllImport] can deal with ordinal values, just curious..

Comment: Declare an overload that accepts `IntPtr` as the second parameter and pass the ordinal value to that parameter.

Comment: Works great! Thanks. Really sorry but last question, is there any function like 'GetProcAddress()' for a global variable? I use '__declspec(dllimport)' for it in C++ but I can't in C#..

Comment: If the variable is exported then you import it with `GetProcAddress`

Comment: I thought GetProcAddress() only works with functions.. I'll try it! Thanks

Comment: It's documented: *If the function succeeds, the return value is the address of the exported function or variable.*